# Demoing an iPhone app to client remotely

Tags: iphone

There might be a really simple answer to this, but I do not know it.

What is the easiest way to demo an iPhone app to a client who is remote?

Would a remote desktop connection to your dev machine be the only way through the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At our company we use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) for all our client support, it's very easy for the client to connect and use and is available on Windows and Mac. He can even use the app himself while you sit back and watch :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have the client's UUID you can build an [Adhoc version](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html) of your app and install it on their phone. You will have to generate a distribution provisioning profile that includes their device ID.

Once you have built your app your can install it on their phone using iTunes. This is probably the trickiest part of the process because it involves your client following fairly complicated technical instructions (something I have failed to successfully do). This problem has been solved by the guys at [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/), I really recommend you check them out, it makes beta/demo distribution pretty easy.

Obviously for this sort of demo would involve you talking your client through the app over phone or video conference.

Answer (score 3):

You can't share iPhone's screen without jailbreaking it. The only way to do it is to share your Mac's screen with iPhone Simulator turned on. There are 2 suitable applications:
[Skype](http://www.skype.com) and [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do in these situations is use either [screenr.com](http://screenr.com) (to record a screen cast in the simulator) or video chat over Skype to show it working on an actual device. These seem to be the easiest and quickest methods without jail breaking the device.

On longer projects (more than a week or so) I like to build an ad-hoc version so they can play with it on their own iOS device. The best tool for this is http://testflightapp.com/ - they have great documentation and you can get up and running very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Download [SimFinger](https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger/wiki/Using-SimFinger) and [Snapz Pro X Free Trial](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/)

Combine these two software to capture video from your simulator. I did same for one of my remote client.

Answer (score 0):

U can make a .ipa file of your application and then send the file to your client. The client can then install the app through iTunes.All he has to do is to drag the ipa file into iTunes and sync it with the device.

For making the ipa file you have to use the archive option in XCode.

P.S -> If u have ever noticed all the app files in iTunes are .ipa files.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac you could just run the app in the simulator and share your screen. But if you don't have a Mac, it's much harder to show a remote customer it running on a device.

In that case I'd recommend [Kickfolio](https://kickfolio.com) for an in-browser iPhone Simulator where you can install your app and then share that with others.

I've blogged about [Getting mobile app builds to your customers](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/04/02/getting-mobile-app-builds-to-your-customers/) which discusses the pros and cons and gives a brief tutorial on using Kickfolio and TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running mac, you can demo the app running on a real ios device (iphone, ipad) by using airplay - then you can use Skype/hangouts/teamviewer to share the live airplay video. I use a little app called airserver/or airsquirrels reflector on my mac to make the mac an airplay target (so it appears in iphone)